# ASP.NET C# Service calling a service without initial .aspx definition

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services, asp.net-ajax

I am trying to call a web service (CalorieCount) from another web service(TotalCalories). Now as far as I am aware/could find you have to define a web service in your .aspx file. My problem is I don't have one (yet) since the form will only have a interaction with the second service.

Is there a way to define the service other than that?

TotalCalories:

```
using ...

namespace Food_Calorie_Calculator
{

    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    //Allow web service to be called --->
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]

    public class TotalCalories : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        public Food CalorieTotal(List<Food> mixedList)
        {

            /* Count the total number of everything */
            foreach (var element in mixedList)
            {
                //Some Code
                aFood = CallCalorieCount(name,weight); <------- Error: namespace but used as var
            }

           //Some Code
            return totalFood;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just assumed that the webreference you've added in the solution is called "CalorieCount", so you should rename it (CalorieCount.CalorieCount) to your name of the refernce.
You have to create an instance of the webservice first, then you can call the methods of it.

Probably for your problem it would be sufficient just to add the method in your TotalCalories class.
Furthermore if the CalculateItem Method is needed to be called from another webservice or site, you can just put the method in your TotalCalories class with [WebMethod], else i would not define it as a webmethod of the service.

```
public class TotalCalories : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    public Food CalorieTotal(List<Food> mixedList)
    {
            ...
            aFood = CalculateItem(name, weight);
            ...
            return 
    }

    [WebMethod] //If needed to call outside of the webservice WebMethod, else just remove the attribute
    public Food CalculateItem(String name, Double weight)
    {
        ...
    }

}
```

Here the code for creating an instance of the webservice and calling the method

```
    CalorieCount.CalorieCount calorieCountService service = new CalorieCount.CalorieCount();
    aFood = calorieCountService.CalculateItem(name,weight);
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. I actually found out how to do it while waiting for a response. Do you mind if I edit your comment to add a explination how it interacts with AJAX/Java script and the .aspx file? I won't remove your explanation, I will just add a bit on the end to improve the explanation for future readers.

Comment: if you wanna use it for ajax too you should add the attribute     [ScriptService] to the webservice class. e.g.  [ScriptService]
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    public class MyService : System.Web.Services.WebService{ ... }